# Does a two-sided book look ugly from the computer? Is it about margins?

Tags: margins, books, single-sided

I think it does. I believe that the main reason is that it's uncomfortable when you scroll down.

Is there a way to keep the same margins in even and odd pages?

Comment: You can always set the left and right margins to the same width: `\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}`

Comment: If you want to scroll down a 2-sided document, then view the left and right pages together. If you don't want to do that, don't create a 2-sided document. The reason the margins are *not* symmetrical for a 2-sided book is because if they were symmetrical, the central margin of the physical book would be twice as wide as the outer margins which would look wrong.

Comment: You can set [oneside] as a document class option, then remove it when you are ready to print.  Note, this also gets rid of the extra blank pages.

Comment: @DG That's a good idea, to me. I'm not sure, though, if it should be 2cm or 3cm or whatever. I think I'll just try to adjust to ~80 characters per line.

Comment: BTW, the title "Does it look ugly" is subjective and not a good fit for TeX.SE.  The question in the body "how to have the same margins" is perfectly fine for TeX.SE.